# Function not show the parent classes after use setTimeOut - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

After using setTimeout in a function that displays the classes of a parent element, the result in `console.log` is undefined.

How can I do this check of the classes after the user triggers a blur in the input?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/diasbass/5rp9kwos/)

```
    <div class="field-wrapper field-pristine">
     <input type="text" class="field-item" value="test">
    </div>

    jQuery('body').on('blur', '.field-wrapper input.field-item', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){    
        console.log($( this ).closest('.field-wrapper').attr('class'));
    }, 1200);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an easy fix but you need to define a new variable `var that = this`. This is because var `this` has changed in the new setTimeout function.

This is what I have done.

```
jQuery('body').on('blur', '.field-wrapper input.field-item', function() {
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($(that).closest('.field-wrapper').attr('class'));
    alert($(that).closest('.field-wrapper').attr('class'));
  }, 1200);
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

You are losing `this` pointer with the function, you can use arrow function that doesn't bind to `this`

```
jQuery('body').on('blur', '.field-wrapper input.field-item', function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log($(this).closest('.field-wrapper').attr('class'));
    }, 1200);
})
```

Comment: it's worth noting that arrow functions are not supported by any IE version and a transpiler such as Babel would be needed to provide full cross-browser support

Comment: @MatthewBrent I really think that the internet should move on, if at 2018 someone still uses `IE` so anyway 60% of the websites won't work for him. whenever I'm developing a website, I'm ignoring IE for 100%, supporting IE can take 30% more developing time, for 2-4% of potential users...

Comment: @DanielKrom I really agree with that sentiment and personally follow it too, however it is important to note that certain corporate environments will not allow for this sort of design.

Comment: I also agree and without creating a long conversation in comments, the browser compatibility is important in so far as no IE browser (even IE11 that is still supported by Microsoft) That might be pretty important for a lot of organisations and it also just completes the answer a little more. It doesn't harm mentioning the browser support

Comment: @MatthewBrent I totally agree that mentioning it is important

Answer (score 1):

This is because the context of `this` changes inside of the callback of the method `setTimeout` what you will have to do here is store `$(this)` like:

```
var myElement = $(this);

// then do the setTimeout and inside use `myElement` instead of `$(this)`
setTimeout(function(){    
  console.log(myElement.closest('.field-wrapper').attr('class'));
}, 1200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `bind` `this` with `setTimeout`

```js
jQuery('body').on('blur', '.field-wrapper input.field-item', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('.field-wrapper').attr('class'));
  }.bind(this), 1200);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-wrapper field-pristine">
  <input type="text" class="field-item" value="test">
</div>
```

Else use arrow function

```js
jQuery('body').on('blur', '.field-wrapper input.field-item', function() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log($(this).closest('.field-wrapper').attr('class')), 1200);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-wrapper field-pristine">
  <input type="text" class="field-item" value="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Probably a typo but the `setTimeout` seems to have changed in to a `setInterval` in your arrow function example.

Comment: @Script47 yup it was a typo.Thanks for pointing it.I have udated